# How can a powerful acidic substance not break down inorganic material?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

A Gelatinous Cube is a massive, slime-based jelly that haunts underground dungeons, and is composed of an acidic substance which breaks down material. These creatures are unintelligent and crawl aimlessly through a dungeon. They feed by engulfing an organic mass and dissolving it inside itself. However, the acid only breaks down organic matter, leaving behind the bones of the victim as well as armor.

These undissolved materials remain in the cube as it moves through a dungeon. This fills the heart of explorers with terror, as they contemplate the grisly date awaiting them. This doesn't make sense however, as acid that is powerful enough to dissolve organic matter completely should logically dissolve everything else as well.

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 4):

The most effective way to get rid of a dead body [is lye solution](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2009/12/how-long-does-it-take-to-dissolve-a-human-body.html)**. Because it breaks down both the amino*acids* in the proteins and the fats.

By comparison, you need a strong *and oxidizing and or dehydrating* acid, and you'll have to wait 2 days instead of merely hours.

Guess what? A basic solution doesn't attack calcium phosphate, the thing your bones are make of.

** I recommend you take me on my word and don't try it at home. It may be illegal in your jurisdiction

Comment: Yes; your basic cube.

Comment: @Willk yeah, basically

Comment: Wow that's clever! Interesting that the exact opposite of an acid has the OP's desired properties

Comment: to be fair most acids will not dissolve bone either. It also means you can kill your slime by feeding it fruit as it will produce a lot of carbon monoxide.

Answer (score 3):

### You are worried about nothing.

This is actually normal, only a few animals produce stomach acid strong enough to dissolve bone (crocodiles). Bones put through normal digestion may show minor signs of being put through acid but they are relatively minor surface effects (etching). Without a way to physically break the bones they will come out almost completely intact. This is why owl pellets and predator dung are often full of easily identifiable bone.

Keep in mind digestion is more about the **enzymes** than the acid anyway, the acid mostly functions to kill bacteria and promote digestion, it is not actually doing the bulk of the digestion. A lot of organisms digest things outside the body then take in the dissolved material.  It is called **External Pre-digestion** and is fairly common in invertebrates. The slimes way of eating is not actually unusual.

Answer (score 3):

**It's not acid, it's other digestion effects**

Instead of being concentrated sulfuric acid, the Cube has many types of enzymes in it, which break up most living tissues.  Small forces within the Cube constantly quest for food nearby, breaking up skin, muscle, fat, etc.

People only call it "acid" because the setting doesn't have pervasive education.

Alternately : the rules are different than from the real world, and the author gets to say what acid does.

Comment: keep in mind many digestive juices are acidic, if for no other reason than to kill bacteria.